# Eclipse fails to build Java Card sample projects

Tags: eclipse, build, javacard

I have installed the new release of Java Card Platform Development Kit, according to the [following guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/install-and-setup-development-kit.htm#JCUGC119). This includes all the prerequisites, as well as version 3.0.5u2 of JCDK. As a heads up, I tried installing this on 2 different computers (one has Win7, the other Win10) and reinstalled everything on both.

The problem I'm encountering is that none of the sample projects will build properly. When I try to build the HelloWorld sample, for example, I get the following text printed in the build console:

```
[ INFO: ] Converter [v3.0.5]
[ INFO: ]     Copyright (c) 1998, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

[ INFO: ] conversion completed with 0 errors and 0 warnings.
[ INFO: ] Converter [v3.0.5]
[ INFO: ]     Copyright (c) 1998, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

[ INFO: ] conversion completed with 0 errors and 0 warnings.
Missing file containing component hashes.
usage: scriptgen [-options] -hashfile <hash file path> <cap File Path>
where options include:
-help           Print this message and exit.
-o <filename>   Output filename. default: stdout
-version        Print version number and exit.
-nobanner       Do not print banner.
-nobeginend     Suppress "CAP_BEGIN", "CAP_END" APDU commands.
-package <pkgname>   Package name.
```

While the regular console has this to say:

```
Executing "$JC_CLASSIC_HOME\bin/converter.bat" -debug -nobanner -out CAP JCA -classdir "$JC_CLASSIC_HOME\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\bin" -d "$JC_CLASSIC_HOME\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\deliverables" -exportpath "$JC_CLASSIC_HOME\api_export_files" -applet 0xA0:0x00:0x00:0x00:0x62:0x03:0x01:0x0C:0x01:0x01 com.sun.jcclassic.samples.helloworld.HelloWorld com.sun.jcclassic.samples.helloworld 0xA0:0x00:0x00:0x00:0x62:0x03:0x01:0x0C:0x01 1.0
Executing "$JC_CLASSIC_HOME\bin/scriptgen.bat" -package com.sun.jcclassic.samples.helloworld -o "$JC_CLASSIC_HOME\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\apdu_scripts/cap-com.sun.jcclassic.samples.helloworld.script" "$JC_CLASSIC_HOME\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\deliverables/com/sun/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/helloworld.cap"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: $JC_CLASSIC_HOME\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\apdu_scripts\cap-com.sun.jcclassic.samples.helloworld.script (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    ... (stack trace)
```

Now, I'm not 100% sure, but I think that when I had version 3.0.5u1 installed, I was able to build the sample projects.

Comment: Are you sure that $JC_CLASSIC_HOME is expanded well? I would not expect it to be present by name in the exception... Check your environment variables, and set the variable!

Comment: Not entirely sure whay you mean by expanded, but I use $JC_CLASSIC_HOME in my above post as a placeholder for my actual path. JC_CLASSIC_HOME is indeed an environment variable, pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Java Card Development Kit 3.0.5u2\.

Comment: DOS/Windows uses `%JC_CLASSIC_HOME%`. I still think this was just the env. var.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the build process of the Java Card Classic Development Kit 3.0.5u2 (jcdk) Eclipse Plugin is broken. During the build of an java card applet, three scripts located in the bin subdirectory of the jcdk installation directory are executed (if using default applet settings in eclipse):

1. converter.bat generating the export file *.exp
2. converter.bat generating cap (and jca) file
3. scriptgen.bat generating the script files for installing the applet to a java card.

The problem is, that scriptgen requires a hashfile containing hashes for the applet components. You can see this if you decompile the class com.sun.javacard.scriptgen.Main of tools.jar in jcdk lib folder.

This hashfile is not generated during the eclipse build process, neither is the scriptgen script called with the corresponding program option "-hashfile <hash-file>". The only workaround currently is using the jcdk tools on the console manually. Therefor you can use the output of console in eclipse and adopt it for your needs.

Example output for a simple test applet:

```
Executing E:\eclipse-oxygen-64bit\JCDKit_305u2\bin/converter.bat -i -debug -out EXP -classdir G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet\bin -d G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet\deliverables -exportpath E:\eclipse-oxygen-64bit\JCDKit_305u2\\api_export_files -applet 0xD0:0x00:0x00:0x00:0x01:0x01:0x01 test.jcdk.applet.TestApplet test.jcdk.applet 0xD0:0x00:0x00:0x00:0x01:0x01 1.0
Executing E:\eclipse-oxygen-64bit\JCDKit_305u2\bin/converter.bat -i -debug -out CAP JCA -classdir G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet\bin -d G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet\deliverables -exportpath E:\eclipse-oxygen-64bit\JCDKit_305u2\\api_export_files -applet 0xD0:0x00:0x00:0x00:0x01:0x01:0x01 test.jcdk.applet.TestApplet test.jcdk.applet 0xD0:0x00:0x00:0x00:0x01:0x01 1.0
Executing E:\eclipse-oxygen-64bit\JCDKit_305u2\bin/scriptgen.bat -package test.jcdk.applet -o G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet\apdu_scripts/cap-test.jcdk.applet.script G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet\deliverables/test/jcdk/applet/javacard/applet.cap
```

Modified to generate the required script files (listed only the last two, first two scripts do not change):

```
    G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet>E:\eclipse-oxygen-64bit\JCDKit_305u2\bin\verifycap.bat -outfile applet.hash E:\eclipse-oxygen-64bit\JCDKit_305u2\api_export_files\java\lang\javacard\lang.exp E:\eclipse-oxygen-64bit\JCDKit_305u2\api_export_files\javacard\framework\javacard\framework.exp .\deliverables\test\jcdk\applet\javacard\applet.exp .\deliverables\test\jcdk\applet\javacard\applet.cap
[ INFO: ] Verifier [v3.0.5]
[ INFO: ]     Copyright (c) 1998, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.


[ INFO: ] Verifying CAP file .\deliverables\test\jcdk\applet\javacard\applet.cap
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/Header.cap               [SHA-256: 22e589e7bbb45e420c2a17d5b8abcc437c52f00ecfb15b48ed3257f87eff62f9]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/Directory.cap            [SHA-256: bc72a8594664c9720c38afab7c87b7dda894088f53faefcac548463a4186fbe9]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/Import.cap               [SHA-256: e58492b256b4af8d7f1860f18e57c5336e254a618c2518c987dcefb33db0a8d0]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/ConstantPool.cap         [SHA-256: 6c5bf615cd3746d52c815e8264b910a41a94217161862a7520087799fd03098b]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/StaticField.cap          [SHA-256: 1ec76ec50280f5d8822179bb1b268ae7c2383d9fbe4d6c2beb427090dbf53dfd]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/RefLocation.cap          [SHA-256: b2b3f5e23eee662b8c406212d5cb291959a8eeddb92e58b9a45941c0b91388be]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/Descriptor.cap           [SHA-256: 292e4bd46d836b8501a19a9ea92b1ec976eca1b4920bb03499236284d17be2d7]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/Class.cap                [SHA-256: 6c68abd77e3481a00ae2462cfc8f416ae38d4d0e4b02c685145c39d30d132526]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/Debug.cap                [SHA-256: 7341f35fee494363bb8b84e8c132399a33a0bb4d39fd9192e92be680c08019d3]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/Method.cap               [SHA-256: 651231359c6bb65fbcb0e3a49f52cee1a682ed7e97610365b374583638757365]
[ INFO: ] Digest for test/jcdk/applet/javacard/Applet.cap               [SHA-256: e1de8850f009796b9b991757dd378353128e10d4bc6400e5bbd970516bf187f1]
[ INFO: ] Verification completed with 0 warnings and 0 errors.
```

(Note: you have to add the path to the jcdk export files used by the applet, these you can find out by activating verbose output in the java card package settings and searching the console output for referenced exp files.)

Then at lease you can generate the install script with the command:

```
G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet>E:\eclipse-oxygen-64bit\JCDKit_305u2\bin/scriptgen.bat -package test.jcdk.applet -o 

G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet\apdu_scripts/cap-test.jcdk.applet.script G:\eclipse_javacard\workspace\TestJCDKApplet\deliverables/test/jcdk/applet/javacard/applet.cap -hashfile applet.hash
ScriptGen [v3.0.5]
    Copyright (c) 1998, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.


APDU script file for CAP file download generated.
```