# Scriptgen verification failure while using JCMathLib

Tags: eclipse, build, javacard

I am trying to develop a JavaCard applet(JCDK version 3.0.5u2) that executes some elliptic curve operations such as scalar multiplication. I have found  [JCMathLib](https://github.com/OpenCryptoProject/JCMathLib) which is a library developed for these kind of operations.

I use eclipse for developing the applet but it gives me an error in the build process after I include the source code of this library, saying that "Hash for libPrac2/javacard/Method.cap could not be verified". I searched online and this error is caused by the scriptgen application which generates the apdu scripts for installing the applet from a cap file. I also used command line to execute each intermediate step to proivde the correct hash file but I got the same error.

I tried the solution mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901909/eclipse-fails-to-build-java-card-sample-projects) question. But it is a different scenario, because the hash file is generated in my case but scriptgen fails to verify.

The error occurs whenever I use any kind of class from the library. It is not related to a specific code segment as far as I can see.

Comment: A bit late but I observed a similar problem some time ago. I was able to solve it by using an older JDK. In particular, 1.8.0-152 which is 8u152 at https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html.